# How to make SVN ignore certain lines of code in a file?

Tags: java, svn, ignore

Me and my Friends are creating a program and using SVN to share code. The problem is that we are using google maps in it, so we need all of us to have different API keys. For now we have commented lines of our API keys in the application, but it is annoying if someone changes that class and commits with his API.

Is there a way to tell not to commit certain lines of code to SVN?

Comment: Why don't you share one API key?

Comment: @Matjaz Because google requires different keys from different locations.

Comment: You could just move cnofiguration to some static java file or even better to resource bundle (.properties file) and "svn ignore" it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the hard-coding from your program, so that the classes are universal (and can be committed to SVN).

Instead, store the config / API key in an external config file or database. Enhance the code to load the config from wherever you've stored it when the application starts.

---

**Update:**

Here's a very simple code example for creating and using a properties file: http://www.bartbusschots.ie/blog/?p=360

Comment: The question is how to make SVN ignore certain lines, not if the selected approach is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can user a file .properties, where you can store the all the API key, for example you can call a property myAPIKey, and the others could be called like APIKey1, APIKey 2.

If you do this, you only have to change the name of the property you want to use to myAPIKey and load it in you java class...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, configuration does not belong to code. Write a .properties file and store the key and rest of properties there.

After that, you should

1) commit a copy of the properties file (maybe properties_svn)

2) make your build process copy properties_svn to properties if the later is not found.

3) enjoy

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to store keys on SVN. It is like storing secret code of your credit card there. O probably writing secret code on the credit card itself.

These keys should be outside SVN on your private environment. If you do not want to create such files implement ability to pass key as an argument or system property.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is "don't do that", as others have already said.

If you *must* surely it's better to put *all* your various keys in there, and then either select the correct one at compile-time (e.g. C preprocessor) or at run time (e.g. based on `hostname`).

Answer (score 1):

You should hold this type of configuration externally to the code, normally in a properties file, injecting the required value at runtime.

I typically use a series of properties files with Spring's `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` each allowing the property values to be overridden as needed down to a specific user, resulting in the following config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
  <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
  <property name="order" value="1"/>
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:my-system.properties</value>
      <value>classpath:my-system-${HOST}.properties</value>
      <value>classpath:my-system-${USERNAME}.properties</value>
   </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

If you're not using Spring you can achieve just the same effect in code like this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

InputStream systemPropertiesStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("my-system.properties");
if (systemPropertiesStream != null) 
{
  try
  {
    properties.load(systemPropertiesStream);
  }
  finally 
  {
    systemPropertiesStream.close();
  }  
}

InputStream hostPropertiesStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("my-system" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() + ".properties");
if (hostPropertiesStream != null) 
{
  try
  {
    properties.load(hostPropertiesStream);
  }
  finally 
  {
    hostPropertiesStream.close();
  }  
}

InputStream userPropertiesStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("my-system" + System.getProperty("user.name") + ".properties");
if (userPropertiesStream != null) 
{
  try
  {
    properties.load(userPropertiesStream);
  }
  finally 
  {
    userPropertiesStream.close();
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually such things are not part of a source code versioning tool. Most developers solve this or similar problems with using a build system. E.g. maven.

With maven for example someone would define different profiles with different property files for different users having different api keys or folder references etc.